# Invert bitmap colors

Tags: java, android, colors

I have the following problem. I have a charting program, and it's design is black, but the charts (that I get from the server as images) are light (it actually uses only 5 colors: red, green, white, black and gray).

To fit with the design inversion does a good job, the only problem is that red and green are inverted also (green -> pink, red -> green).

Is there a way to invert everything except those 2 colors, or a way to repaint those colors after inversion?
And how costly are those operations (since I get the chart updates pretty often)?

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE**

I tried replacing colors with setPixel method in a loop

```
for(int x = 0 ;x < chart.getWidth();x++) {
        for(int y = 0;y < chart.getHeight();y++) {
            final int replacement = getColorReplacement(chart.getPixel(x, y));
            if(replacement != 0) {
                chart.setPixel(x, y, replacement);
            }
        }
    }
```

Unfortunetely, the method takes too long (~650ms), is there a faster way to do it, and will setPixels() method work faster?

Comment: You wrote: *"it actually uses only 5 colors"* but you need to be careful.

What you consider a "color" is probably not what the OS will consider a "color".

For example, in ARGB 32 bit, 0xFF0000 looks to you like "red".  But so does 0xFF0001.  Yet they are two different colors.

Comment: Thank, but it really only uses 5 colors. Since I have access to where charts are generated, they are specially made very simple :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Manipulating a bitmap is much faster if you copy the image data into an int array by calling getPixels only once, and don't call any function inside the loop. Just manipulate the array, then call setPixels at the end.

Something like that:

```
int length = bitmap.getWidth()*bitmap.getHeight();
int[] array = new int[length];
bitmap.getPixels(array,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
// If the bitmap is in ARGB_8888 format
  if (array[i] == 0xff000000){
    array[i] = 0xffffffff;
  } else if ...
  }
}
bitmap.setPixels(array,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried similar method, but with IntBuffer, and Bitmap's copyPixelsToBuffer(), but it still took some 250ms.
Your method takes some ~100ms

Answer (score 2):

If you have it available as `BufferedImage`, you can access its raster and edit it as you please.

```
WritableRaster raster = my_image.getRaster();

// Edit all the pixels you wanna change in the raster (green -> red, pink -> green)
// for (x,y) in ...
// raster.setPixel(x, y, ...) 

my_image.setData(raster);
```

Comment: Umm.. I guess android doesn't have BufferedImage, or WritableRaster :(

Comment: Oh, sorry, this is a java solution ...I thought it would be available on android as well ...my bad.

Comment: It actually is available. Bitmap object has setPixel method (that changes the value of any pixel). Just need to loop through all pixel and replace with substitutes :)

Answer (score 2):

OK seen that you're really only using 5 colors it's quite easy.

Regarding performances, I don't know about Android but I can tell you that in Java using *setRGB* is amazingly slower than getting back the data buffer and writing directly in the int[].

When I write "amazingly slower", to give you an idea, on OS X 10.4 the following code:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        img.setRGB(x,y,0xFFFFFFFF);
    }
}
```

can be 100 times (!) slower than:

```
for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ ) {
    for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ ) {
        array[y*width+x] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
}
```

You read correctly: one hundred time.  Measured on a Core 2 Duo / Mac Mini / OS X 10.4.

*(of course you need to first get access to the underlying int[] array but hopefully this shouldn't be difficult)*

I cannot stress enough that the problem ain't the two for loops: in both cases it's the same unoptimized for loops.  So it's really setRGB that is the issue here.

I don't know it works on Android, but you probably should get rid of setRGB if you want something that performs well.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way would be to use [AvoidXfermode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/AvoidXfermode.html) to repaint just those colors you want changed - you could then switch between any colors you want. You just need to do something like this:

```
// will change red to green
Paint change1 = new Paint();
change1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
change1.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.RED, 245, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(chart);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, change1);

// rinse, repeat for other colors
```

You may need to play with the tolerance for the `AvoidXfermode`, but that should do what you want a lot faster than a per-pixel calculation. Also, *make sure* your chart image is in ARGB8888 mode. By default, Android tends to work with images in RGB565 mode, which tends to mess up color calculations like you want to use - to be sure, you can make sure your image is both in ARGB8888 mode *and* mutable by calling `Bitmap chart = chartFromServer.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true);` before you setup the Xfermode.

**Clarification**: to change other colors, you wouldn't have to re-load the images all over again, you would just have to create other Paints with the appropriate colors you want changed like so:

```
// changes green to red
Paint change1 = new Paint();
change1.setColor(Color.GREEN);
change1.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.RED, 245, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));

// changes white to blue
Paint change2 = new Paint();
change2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
change2.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.WHITE, 245, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));

// ... other Paints with other changes you want to apply to this image

Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(chart);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, change1);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, change2);
//...
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, changeN);
```

Comment: It's definetely faster, but how do I change all colors at once?
I mean, If I have only 2 colors (white, black) and want to inverse, after making all black pixels -> white I can't make all white pixels black, since it will inverse all white pixels (old and new) to black. So in the end I will get a totally black image.
I thought about using some kind of buffer color for black&white, but won't it cost a lot of time?
And also, after I do this more than once, only the last changes are reflected.

Comment: You should be able to use *almost* white/black/green/whatever colors and small tolerances to remove the need for an intermediate step. If you have two colors, say `0xFFFF0000` and `0xFF00FF00` that you want to switch, you should be able to setup two Paints with Xfermodes, one that does `0xFFFF0000` -> `0xFF00EE00` (*looks* green, but it isn't exactly `0xFF00FF00`, *true* green), and one that then does `0xFF00FF00` -> `0xFFFF0000`. The key is that you have to setup separate Paints for the two color changes and apply them to the image in the right order.

Comment: I see. If I get it correctly, while changing one color may take 18ms, changing 5 colors will take ~90, right.

It's actually a very fast solutions, but if I'll have 10 colors tomorrow, it will take longer than pixel by pixel substitution.

Isn't there a way to apply multiple changes at once?

Comment: If you mean using a single Paint to do all of your color changes, I can't think of an obvious way off the top of my head. But I also don't know that the time will scale linearly with the entire time it takes for one color, since you would just run them in quick succession: 
`Canvas c = new Canvas();
c.setBitmap(chart);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, change1);
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, change2);
//...
c.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, changeN);
`
I would think that some of the 18ms would be in the image copying and loading, and wouldn't be duplicated in just repeated calls to `drawRect()`.