# Invert colors of drawable

Tags: android, colors, drawable

Is it possible to "invert" colors in a `Drawable`? Kind of what you have in a negative, you know?

I know it's possible to change a `Drawable` to black and white, but what about inverting colors?

Answer (score 67):

After some research I found out that solution is much simpler than I thought.

Here it is:

```
  /**
   * Color matrix that flips the components (<code>-1.0f * c + 255 = 255 - c</code>)
   * and keeps the alpha intact.
   */
  private static final float[] NEGATIVE = { 
    -1.0f,     0,     0,    0, 255, // red
        0, -1.0f,     0,    0, 255, // green
        0,     0, -1.0f,    0, 255, // blue
        0,     0,     0, 1.0f,   0  // alpha  
  };

  drawable.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(NEGATIVE));
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, it works for an image view with any source (drawable, bitmap, etc.). Just do the same ```imageView.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(NEGATIVE))```

Answer (score 2):

Best way to do this would be to convert your drawable into a bitmap:

```
Bitmap fromDrawable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.drawable_resource);
```

And then invert it as per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4625618/1154026

And then back to a drawable if you need to:

```
Drawable invertedDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),fromDrawable);
```

Answer (score 1):

According your answer, I've created short Kotlin extension for Drawable

```
private val negative = floatArrayOf(
    -1.0f,     .0f,     .0f,    .0f,  255.0f, 
      .0f,   -1.0f,     .0f,    .0f,  255.0f, 
      .0f,     .0f,   -1.0f,    .0f,  255.0f, 
      .0f,     .0f,     .0f,   1.0f,     .0f 
)

fun Drawable.toNegative() {
    this.colorFilter = ColorMatrixColorFilter(negative)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin extension function for ImageView:

```
fun ImageView.invertColors() {
    val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffffffff.toInt(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    setColorFilter(colorFilter)
}
```

and also for Drawable

```
fun Drawable.invertColors() {
    val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(0xffffffff.toInt(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)
    setColorFilter(colorFilter)
}
```