# Night mode using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

Is it possible to implement night mode of maps using osmdroid?

My idea is add some filter to all resources, but maybe there is some better solution?

Answer (score 7):

From version 5.1 you can set it this way:

```
this.mMapView.getOverlayManager().getTilesOverlay().setColorFilter(TilesOverlay.INVERT_COLORS);
```

Answer (score 5):

The default `ColorMatrixColorFilter` version of `TilesOverlay.INVERT_COLORS` is not to my liking. So, I've made my own custom version by changing the map's color filter for the night mode (after 7 PM and before 7 AM), taking cue from [Medium: Welcome to the (Color) Matrix](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/welcome-to-the-color-matrix-64d112e3f43d):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH", Locale.getDefault());
String hour = format.format(Tools.getTime());

//night mode after 7 PM and before 7 AM
if (Integer.valueOf(hour) < 7 || Integer.valueOf(hour) > 19) {
    //taking cue from https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/welcome-to-the-color-matrix-64d112e3f43d
    ColorMatrix inverseMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
            -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 255f,
            0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 255f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 255f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f
    });

    int destinationColor = Color.parseColor("#FF2A2A2A");
    float lr = (255.0f - Color.red(destinationColor))/255.0f;
    float lg = (255.0f - Color.green(destinationColor))/255.0f;
    float lb = (255.0f - Color.blue(destinationColor))/255.0f;
    ColorMatrix grayscaleMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
            lr, lg, lb, 0, 0, //
            lr, lg, lb, 0, 0, //
            lr, lg, lb, 0, 0, //
            0, 0, 0, 0, 255, //
    });
    grayscaleMatrix.preConcat(inverseMatrix);
    int dr = Color.red(destinationColor);
    int dg = Color.green(destinationColor);
    int db = Color.blue(destinationColor);
    float drf = dr / 255f;
    float dgf = dg / 255f;
    float dbf = db / 255f;
    ColorMatrix tintMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
            drf, 0, 0, 0, 0, //
            0, dgf, 0, 0, 0, //
            0, 0, dbf, 0, 0, //
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //
    });
    tintMatrix.preConcat(grayscaleMatrix);
    float lDestination = drf * lr + dgf * lg + dbf * lb;
    float scale = 1f - lDestination;
    float translate = 1 - scale * 0.5f;
    ColorMatrix scaleMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[] {
            scale, 0, 0, 0, dr * translate, //
            0, scale, 0, 0, dg * translate, //
            0, 0, scale, 0, db * translate, //
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0, //
    });
    scaleMatrix.preConcat(tintMatrix);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(scaleMatrix);
    surfaceView.getOverlayManager().getTilesOverlay().setColorFilter(filter);
}
```

[image: Sample night mode using a custom ColorMatrixColorFilter with Mapnik]

Note: if you have used `ScaleBarOverlay`, you may need to change its color to make it more visible in the night mode.

To help with finding the right matrix, I use this convenient tool [colormatrix-viewer](http://colormatrix-viewer)

Answer (score 2):

Osmdroid just displays map tiles. So you are free to switch to an different map provider / style that fits your "night mode" best. For example the old [cloudmade midnight commander](http://stamen.com/clients/cloudmade)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change style of tile using osmdroid?

Comment: @JMichal By setting a different tile source (also called tile provider).

Comment: tile providers and tile sources are two different things. A tile source is something like mapquest, bing, usgs, etc. A tile provider is, load from http, load from database, load from zip, etc.

Comment: @spy In OSM-speak these two terms usually refer to the same thing. However it might be possible that osmdroid uses these terms for referring to different things - which seems to be a bad idea.

Comment: They are not the same thing. The class hierarchies are completely different and they do not share a common ancestor. Up to 4.3, you couldn't change tile providers programmatically, only the tile source. I have a pull request to make it configurable (useful for offline tile users)

Answer (score 1):

a slightly more elegant solution to switching map tile providers, would be to alter osmdroid slightly to invert the color scheme of all tiles before they are drawn. Not terribly difficult to do.

This post shows you how to invert the colors
[Invert colors of drawable Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841787/invert-colors-of-drawable-android)

Here's the class to alter
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/overlay/TilesOverlay.java
probably around line 170 would be a great place to put some boolean logic to toggle on and off night mode, then use the matrix to flip the colors.

You mileage will vary with this, as not all tile sources will look good with this. Satellite imagery, such as bing or USGS Sat will likely get brighter. Road/topo/hillshade/mapquest/osm maps will probably get darker.

Edit: a better place to inject the change is "onTileReadyToShow".
Good news, it's looks really cool. Performance is about the same as it was before the change

Comment: FYI, i filed a ticket with osmdroid on github and pull request for it.

Comment: Just for reference, the ticket is at https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/133

Comment: to add, android has support for a night variant. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html which will flip resources over to an alternate mode