# Android Canvas use filter

Tags: android, canvas

I want to use an inversion color filter in a onDrawCanvas listener. I can do it when I draw using Bitmaps using ColorFilters.

I tried creating a new Paint object and setting a ColorFilter, but that overrides the original canvas too.

Comment: Is there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841787/invert-colors-of-drawable-android ?

Comment: How to use ColorFilter for a canvas object directly?

Comment: You can't do so. `Canvas` is low level object. Use `Bitmap` with `Canvas` for drawing and after apply filter and just draw your bitmap on the `Canvas` that you need

Comment: Or set a filter for the `Paint`

Comment: I have an onDraw listener, which gives me a Canvas object. How can I manipulate this directly? I tried making a new Paint object with only ColorFilter set, but that erases the original Canvas.

Comment: What for are you need to erase it? Why do you not draw over it? Although, you can erase it just draw rectangle area with needed parameters

Comment: How to draw a filter on a Canvas directly? I don't have the image bitmap with me but just the canvas object.

Comment: You cannot apply a filter to the canvas object directly