# Android change item's list layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have a DrawerLayout with navigation menu(there is list of menu elements), I want to change some properties. Currently it looks like this

[image]

and I need something like:

[image]

So how is it possible to change color text, imageview tint, marginLeft and small green line?

List item is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mynavigationbackground"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:tint="#109039"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gallery"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#109039"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

For change background color I use these xml files:

mynavigationbackground:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigationactivated" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigationactivated" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigationactivated" android:state_activated="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/navigationnoactivated"></item>
</selector>
```

navigationactivated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#4064D864"></solid>
</shape>
```

and navigationnoactivated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
</shape>
```

I tried to use tint and margin properties in these files but it doesn't work.
Is there any way to make this effect in xml?

I tried to do it programmatically (by onClick), but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer.  it could be useful.
It is about inverted colors and I see your images and one is the opposite of the other. 
[Invert colors of drawable Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841787/invert-colors-of-drawable-android)

Comment: to be honest, i'm not sure which one is opposite of the other and how to change one of needed properties